# using fake API from jsonpalceholder, how to append the returned data from api to a list - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, jsonplaceholder

I am using API with javascript for first time, so I am using jsonplaceholder fake API.

I have an array of objects and I am trying to iterate over a property in this array of object but I got this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
```

Here is my code

```js
const api_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
let specialisty = document.getElementById('specialisty-menu');
async function getUser() {
  // Making an API call (request)
  // and getting the response back
  const response = await fetch(api_url);

  // Parsing it to JSON format
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

  let name = data.map((a) => a.name);
  console.log(name);
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    console.log(name[i]);
    let item = document.createElement('a');
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name[i]));
    specialisty.appendChild(item);
  }
}

getUser();
```

```html
<div id="specialisty-menu"></div>
```

Comment: The code you included appears to be working. Perhaps the error is somewhere else? Or did you not have an appropriate target for `document.getElementById('specialisty-menu')` in your HTML?

Comment: thank you very much, yes it was a target problem

Comment: Your javascript is loaded before the Dom tree and therefore your variable `let specialisty` will result into a null (and appendChild wont exist). Solution use put the attribute `defer` in the script tag that loads your js.